# Android Lint Error: Missing Class when using XML from library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint, android-lint

We are currently getting error when running the Lint using Gradle wrapper command similar to [this](https://googlesamples.github.io/android-custom-lint-rules/checks/MissingClass.md.html). The project is running well and has no errors, but we wanted to know if this is a known issue with Android's Lint or there is need more configuration when using library's classes for custom UI? The library is a custom TextView that handles HTML, we are using one of its classes to the XML which works fine but it seems the Linter cannot understand or find it properly.